# creating RESTful like urls despite heavy limitations

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-3.5

Environment: 
.Net Framework 3.5 SP1
WebForms Application

What would be the best way to mimic url routing in a web form application with authentication in mind?
I've researched things like: WebClient class, URL Rewriting, Custom HTTP Handlers. Any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might help you

[ASP.NET FriendlyUrls - cleaner URLs, easier Routing, and Mobile Views for ASP.NET Web Forms](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx)

Comment: Requirements say needs .Net Framework 4 but I can only use 3.5 sp1 or earlier.

Comment: Sorry. I used one like this before and didn't pay attention to the requirements. My bad, but perhaps this link can help you -  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668202(v=vs.90).aspx